# How to associate a domain name and IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, slicehost

The situation is as follows:

I am renting a dedicated server using [SliceHost](https://web.archive.org/web/20130215192914/http://www.slicehost.com/). On this server I have installed a small HTTPServer. I can verify that it works by nativating directly to its IP address ([example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927062746/http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/1049/webserverdefaultpage.png)).

I have also purchased a domain name from [gandi.net](https://www.gandi.net/en) and would like to link it with to my server. However, I'm having much trouble finding clear instructions on how to create this link. After a few hours of reading documentation and trying out things I ended up the following configuration.

- on the DNS registrar I have specified the following settings:

[image]

- on the Slicehost server I specified these "records":

[image]

But it doesn't seem to work. I end up on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20150927035232/http://img404.imageshack.us/img404/3017/domainnamenotavailable.png) telling me the domain name is not available.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that everything is configured correctly. Public WHOIS records are pointing to the right website that you're referring to by IP address (and your screenshot)

With the DNS system, it can take anywhere from 6 hours to 72 hours for DNS changes to propagate across the Internet. Those changes include changing the master DNS servers (what you did), updating IP address, adding sub-domains, or editing existing records.

ISP's are notoriously slow on updating their DNS servers. They can take as long as 24-48 hours. Public DNS services like OpenDNS and Google DNS can be as quick as 3-4 hours.

Comment: By the way, to elaborate a bit more. If you typed in your domain before you made those changes, your computer, and your router, and your ISP will have the "old" DNS information cached. It looks like you visited the domain on your computer, saw it was available, then registered it. However, since your ISP cached it as NX Domain (non-existent), you may have to wait for the cache to clear from your ISP before you'll get a correct response. Again, this goes along with how bad ISPs are about keeping their DNS fresh.

Comment: Most resolvers never cache NXDOMAIN.

Comment: It seems you were correct. After some waiting it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
helium:~ fahad$ host stacked-crooked.com
stacked-crooked.com has address 173.203.57.63
```

The record is there, and servers are answering correctly. As James said, you need to wait for caches to expire.